# tengo un inconveniente al momento de querer acomodar las columnas en tkinker ya que entre cada columna se queda mucha separació

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]ya e intentado muchas cosas , funciones separadas para la creación de la tabla y los campos , crear una primero la tabla y luego los campos y viceversa y siempre queda mucha separación entre las columnas

aquí les dejo el código en la parte de la creación de los campos en column estoy dejando solo 1 línea de separación entre cada uno de los campos y en la ventana queda mucha separación yo e intentado crear en funciones separadas la creación de la tabla , y los campos y aun sigue sin acomodarse lo que si probe es que subi la tabla hasta arriba y la separación entre los campos se arreglo y si quedaron acomodados pero cuando la quiero poner uno junto a la otra se pone la gran separación entre las columnas

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def crear_tabla_productos(parent):
    # Crear un marco para la tabla de productos
    frame_tabla_productos = ttk.Frame(parent)
    frame_tabla_productos.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

    # Crear la tabla de productos dentro del marco
    tabla_productos = ttk.Treeview(frame_tabla_productos, columns=("Código", "Marca", "Modelo", "Descripción", "Precio", "Stock"), show="headings", height=10)
    tabla_productos.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

    tabla_productos.heading("Código", text="Código")
    tabla_productos.heading("Marca", text="Marca")
    tabla_productos.heading("Modelo", text="Modelo")
    tabla_productos.heading("Descripción", text="Descripción")
    tabla_productos.heading("Precio", text="Precio")
    tabla_productos.heading("Stock", text="Stock")

    # Ajustar el ancho de las columnas
    tabla_productos.column("#0", width=0)  # Columna invisible
    tabla_productos.column("Código", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Marca", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Modelo", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Descripción", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Precio", width=50)
    tabla_productos.column("Stock", width=50)

    return tabla_productos

def crear_interfaz():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Agregar Nuevo Producto")
    root.geometry("825x440")

    frame_contenido = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame_contenido.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    # Título de la tabla de productos
    label_lista_productos = ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Lista de Productos:")
    label_lista_productos.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=4, pady=(0, 10), sticky="w")

    # Crear la tabla de productos utilizando la función
    tabla_productos = crear_tabla_productos(frame_contenido)

    # Etiqueta "Agregar Nuevo Producto"
    label_agregar_producto = ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Agregar Nuevo Producto:")
    label_agregar_producto.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, pady=(0, 10), sticky="w")

    # Campos para ingresar valores de nuevos productos (disposición vertical)
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Código:").grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Marca:").grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=2, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Modelo:").grid(row=3, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=3, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Descripción:").grid(row=4, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=4, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Precio:").grid(row=5, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=5, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_contenido, text="Stock:").grid(row=6, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_contenido).grid(row=6, column=3, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky="we")
    
    # Botones
    ttk.Button(frame_contenido, text="Agregar Producto").grid(row=7, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=(0, 1), sticky="we")
    ttk.Button(frame_contenido, text="Modificar Producto").grid(row=7, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=(0, 1), sticky="we")
    ttk.Button(frame_contenido, text="Eliminar Producto").grid(row=7, column=4, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=(0, 1), sticky="we")

    # Configuración del tamaño de las columnas
    frame_contenido.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame_contenido.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    frame_contenido.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    frame_contenido.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    frame_contenido.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()

# Ejemplo de uso
crear_interfaz()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los grandes espacios que quedan por encima del label/entry del campo "Descripcion"  con respecto a  los otros? ¿o al espacio entre el treeview y los campos de entrada de la derecha? Este ultimo se debe al botón "Agregar Producto"...

Comment: Entre los campos de entrada de la derecha que apresar de que tienen solo 1 columna de diferencia

Comment: aqui te dejo en link para que veas como me queda https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YRyyOCx-GxkYqNUvX7uSsGbG83doOB4H?usp=sharing lo de la derecha la separacion tan grande que hay entre uno y otro te subi la foto a drive porque no me deja pegarla en el comentario

Comment: Para agregar información relevante a la pregunta o agregar imágenes aclaratorias es mejor que edites la propia pregunta. A ver, las columnas determinan en todo caso el espaciado vertical, es decir, el espacio entre la tabla y los campos por ejemplo. El espaciado entre los campos de la derecha entre si depende de la configuración de las filas. Lo mas disruptivo que veo es la separación tan grande que hay del campo "Descripción" con respecto a "Modelo" y "Precio", esto  se debe a  que usa la misma fila que el treeview (tabla_productos) y la atura de la fila se adapta para poder contenerlo.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y coloque la foto asi es como me queda y cuando te refires a "la separación tan grande que hay del campo "Descripción" con respecto a "Modelo" y "Precio", esto se debe a que usa la misma fila que el treeview (tabla_productos) y la atura de la fila se adapta para poder contenerlo. " a que te refieres ?

Comment: Solo intento aclarar cual es exactamente el espacio que no deseas tener para ver si pudo dar una respuesta, quizás seria mas fácil si marcas en la captura el espacio problemático o un esquema de la estructura que desearías, por ejemplo, no se si buscas un resultado algo asi: https://imgur.com/a/5DMCJp1

Comment: ya edite la foto y quiero que los compos estes mas juntso y no con esa separacion que esta en la imagen que esta en la publicaicion y referente a la imagen que pusiste si es algo asi , es algo parecido a esto tambien lo que estoy  buscando https://imgur.com/a/Bjg28Cj no exactamente pero esa distribucion

Comment: crees que me puedas pasar el codigo de esa interfaz brou?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cosas que determinan la separación que existe entre las filas de cada campo (*label* + *entrie*):

- Obviamente el *padding* explícitamente indicado a grid:

  ```
  ttk.Label(...).grid(..., pady=5, sticky="e")
                          |______|
  ```
- Por otro lado las filas tendrán la altura mínima para acomodar el widget más alto presente en la misma. En el caso de la fila 4 tenemos posicionados el *label* y el *entry* para el campo "Descripción" pero también la tabla (`tabla_productos`):

  ```
  frame_tabla_productos.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
  ```

  El espacio extra necesario para mostrar la tabla hace que esta fila sea más alta que el resto y como consecuencia el espaciado entre el "campo Descripción" y el campo anterior y posterior al mismo es mucho mayor que el que tienen los otros "campos" entre si. Ten también en cuenta que configuras los pesos para las columnas, pero no para las filas.

`grid` es muy buena opción para posicionar widgets en rejilla cuando estos son similares entre si, concretamente cuando los widgets en una misma fila/columna son similares en tamaño o al menos proporcionales, como el caso de tu formulario (labels/entries). Cuando esto no es así, se puede intentar jugar con `columnspan`/`rowspan` y los pesos de cada fila/columna para acomodarlo todo, pero por lo general es mejor opción no intentar acomodarlo todo en un solo padre sino seguir una estrategia de "divide y vencerás" y fragmentar las diferentes partes de la interfaz en diferentes frames y luego combinar `grid`/`pack`/`place` según convenga en cada caso.

En tu caso, yo agruparía el formulario en un frame, la tabla en otro y los botones en otro. Esto facilita luego posicionar cada parte de la interfaz en su sitio además de que cada frame puede usar un gestor de geometría distinto si es necesario.

Hay mil formas de estructura la interfaz además de formas de hacerla o no *responsive*, esto por tanto sería solo un ejemplo poniendo en practica la idea comentada:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def crear_tabla_productos(parent):
    # Crear la tabla de productos dentro del marco
    tabla_productos = ttk.Treeview(
        parent,
        columns=("Código", "Marca", "Modelo", "Descripción", "Precio", "Stock"),
        show="headings", height=10
        )
    tabla_productos.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

    tabla_productos.heading("Código", text="Código")
    tabla_productos.heading("Marca", text="Marca")
    tabla_productos.heading("Modelo", text="Modelo")
    tabla_productos.heading("Descripción", text="Descripción")
    tabla_productos.heading("Precio", text="Precio")
    tabla_productos.heading("Stock", text="Stock")

    # Ajustar el ancho de las columnas
    tabla_productos.column("#0", width=0)  # Columna invisible
    tabla_productos.column("Código", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Marca", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Modelo", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Descripción", width=80)
    tabla_productos.column("Precio", width=50)
    tabla_productos.column("Stock", width=50)

    return tabla_productos

def crear_interfaz():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Agregar Nuevo Producto")
    root.geometry("825x440")

    frame_tabla = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Lista de Productos")
    frame_form = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Agregar Nuevo Producto")
    frame_form_btns = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame_ctrl_btns = ttk.Frame(root)

    frame_tabla.grid(
        row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=(10, 5), pady=(10, 5), sticky="nsew"
        )
    frame_form.grid(
        row=0, column=1, padx=(5, 10), pady=(10, 5), sticky="nsew"
        )
    frame_ctrl_btns.grid(
        row=2, column=0, padx=(5, 10), pady=(5, 10), sticky="sew"
        )
    frame_form_btns.grid(
        row=1, column=1, padx=(5, 10), pady=(5, 10), sticky="sew"
        )

    frame_form.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Crear la tabla de productos utilizando la función
    tabla_productos = crear_tabla_productos(frame_tabla)
    tabla_productos.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    # Campos para ingresar valores de nuevos productos (disposición vertical)
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Código:"
        ).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Marca:"
        ).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Modelo:"
        ).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Descripción:"
        ).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Precio:"
        ).grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")
    ttk.Label(frame_form, text="Stock:"
        ).grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=2, sticky="e")
    ttk.Entry(frame_form
        ).grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=2, sticky="we")

    # Botones
    ttk.Button(frame_ctrl_btns, text="Salir"
        ).pack(side="left", padx=1)
    ttk.Button(frame_form_btns, text="Agregar Producto"
        ).pack(side="left", padx=1)
    ttk.Button(frame_form_btns, text="Modificar Producto"
        ).pack(side="left", padx=1)
    ttk.Button(frame_form_btns, text="Eliminar Producto"
        ).pack(side="left", padx=1)

    root.mainloop()

# Ejemplo de uso
crear_interfaz()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Notas

- He usado LabelFrame en vez de Frame + Label de título. Esto realmente no importa mucho, si no te gusta puedes usar la segunda opción.
- He sacado el posicionamiento del widget (llamada a `grid`) de la función `crear_tabla_productos`. Conceptualmente la función debería limitarse a construir y retornar el widget, sin posicionarlo o modificar nada del widget raíz.
- La interfaz se adapta si se redimensiona la ventana, incrementando o reduciendo el tamaño de la tabla. Esto se hace a través de los pesos:

  ```
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
  ```
- Idealmente el *treeview* debería implementar también scrollbars, al menos vertical, si provees que el numero de filas exceda las que se puedan mostrar con ese tamaño de la ventana, pero esto se sale de la pregunta.

Comment: wao bro muchas gracias ya entendi y logre acomodar los campos